# javascript: waiting until property of an element is ready to continue

Tags: javascript

I have a property of an element that is injected into my page from a 3rd party:

```
document.querySelector('#embed-container #mf2-events').jsMF2
```

the jsMF2 is said injected property. I need to wait until the jsMF2 property is defined in order to do work with it. Originally, I just set a timeout, but this is undesirable for many reasons. Is there a way I can spin until the property or set a callback? If this was a C program, I would write something like this:

```
    while (document.querySelector('#embed-container #mf2-events').jsMF2 === undefined ||
           document.querySelector('#embed-container #mf2-events').jsMF2 === null) { } 

    // do work
```

Comment: You mean in a *multi-threaded* C program that's what you'd do. JavaScript in browsers (other than when used as web workers) is indeed run on a single thread.

Comment: You will either need to poll with `setTimeout()` or you can use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) in a modern browser.  Spinning in a `while` loop will just lock up the browser and it will never succeed because no other code can run to actually cause the change to occur.

Comment: @user3689167: Right, but if the program were truly single-threaded, it would busy-wait forever -- because nothing ever gets a chance to set jsMF2. To do that *while* busy-waiting, you need at least two threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want a busy-wait, because then no other JavaScript can run (not to mention large parts of the browser UI), and so the property won't get defined.

*Ideally*, whatever's providing that property would have an event it fires that you can hook into. I'm going to assume that you've looked and not found one. :-)

Once support for the latest stuff in ECMAScript6 (aka "ES6") becomes widespread (it isn't at present), you *might* be able to use [`Proxy`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-proxy-constructor) for this (provided your target browsers allowed `Proxy` on their HTML element instances). But sufficiently widespread support for `Proxy` will take a couple of years if not longer (and `Proxy` can't be shimmed/polyfilled). (In ES7, you could use [`Object.observe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe), but presumably `Proxy`, which is defined by the current [as of June 2015] standard, will be broadly-supported before an ES7 technology is.)

Until/unless you can use `Proxy`, a timer is indeed the correct way to handle this situation. It can be a really aggressive timer if necessary.

If the *element* is known to exist but you're waiting for the property:

```
check(function(element) {
    // It's there now, use it
    // x = element.jsMF2
});

function check(callback) {
    var element = document.querySelector('#embed-container #mf2-events');
    if (element && 'jsMF2' in element) {
        setTimeout(callback.bind(null, element), 0);
    } else {
        setTimeout(check.bind(null, callback), 0);
    }
}
```

Most browsers will fire that timer *immediately* when the JavaScript thread is available the first couple of times, then throttle it back to at least a 4ms delay for subsequent calls. Still pretty fast.

You don't have to be hyper-aggressive, though; humans are slow compared to computers, you could probably use 10, 20, or even 50ms.

If there's **any** chance that the property won't appear, you want to stop that repeated series of `setTimeout` eventually (after a second, after 10 seconds, after 30 seconds, after 60 seconds, whatever's appropriate to your use case). You can do that by remembering when you started, and then simply giving up rather than rescheduling if it's been too long:

```
var started = Date.now();

check(function(element) {
    // It's there now, use it
    // x = element.jsMF2
});

function check(callback) {
    var element = document.querySelector('#embed-container #mf2-events');
    if (element && 'jsMF2' in element) {
        setTimeout(callback.bind(null, element), 0);
    } else {
        if (Date.now() - started > 1000) { // 1000ms = one second
            // Fail with message
        } else {
            setTimeout(check.bind(null, callback), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Side note: The query

```
var document.querySelector('#embed-container #mf2-events');
```

...is a bit odd. It says: Give me the first element with the `id` `mf2-events` found inside an element with the `id` `embed-container`. But `id` values **must** be unique on the page. So all that really says is "Get tme the `#mfs-events` element, but only if it's inside a `#embed-container` element."

Unless that's *really* what you meant, the dramatically faster

```
var document.getElementById('mf2-events');
```

...would be the way to go.

Comment: please do not setTimeout with 0. It burn battery if not CPU

Comment: @DennisCheung: No, it doesn't. Obviously you don't want to do it forever, but it's just running code, like any other program runs code. Use cases for correctly-coded `setTimeout(..., 0)` are **extremely** common.

Comment: It do.

https://plus.google.com/+PeterKasting/posts/GpL63A1K2TF

Sleep longer the CPU, less battery you wasted

Comment: @DennisCheung: Again: It's just running code at an appropriate time, to do something useful. That's all. (And it's a **lot** less harmful than a busy-wait.) Let's have no FUD about "burning battery if not CPU" please. The logical conclusion of "don't burn battery, even to do something useful" is to not do anything at all.

Comment: Without the context, you don't know that the "running code" doing until a 3rd party make the change.

That means, It could be some network load, UI animation, CPU process(any you try to steal cpu time from it), or user interaction.

In most cases, it just burn CPU and waste.

I use setTimeout, 0,  but only use it for "fix the stupid execution order" that I do not poll again.

Comment: @DennisCheung: Sometimes polling is your only option. Used judiciously, and only when necessary, it's fine.

Comment: @user3689167: Gah! I left out a `return` (but it's better done with `else`). Fixed.

Comment: @user3689167: Thanks for the `element =` fix. Got auto-rejected by the system when I edited the answer without seeing it, but I've folded it in now.

Answer (score 0):

The only real way out here is to use a callback. How is the property set? If it is set by, say, ajax request, you need to add a function as the request parameter that will be run when the request is satisfied. The topics you will probably need are callbacks, asynchronous JavaScript and maybe promises, which are modern approach to async calla.

Comment: I am not really sure how the property gets set, it is injected via a 3rd party which I have no access to

Answer (score -1):

There were [DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) [Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) which is not very popular and later replace it with a new standard [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

But you should [check if your target browser support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver) or implement both.

---

EDIT: You may also use [Object.observe()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) if the property is not an dom attribute.

Comment: `jsMF2` isn't anything a mutation observer can observe. It's an expando property. Mutation observers can only observe DOM changes.

Comment: it return from document.querySelector. it is a DOMElement. It can be observed.

Comment: Just try it. Yes, the *element* is a DOM element. That doesn't make the expando property a DOM property that can be observed. Think about it, what would you tell the observer to observe? `childList`? It's not a child node.
`attributes`? `attributeOldValue`? `attributeFilter`? It's not an attribute.
`characterData`? `characterDataOldValue`? It's not character data.
`subtree`? Again, it's not a node.

Comment: Heck, even some DOM-defined reflected properties can't be observed with a MutationObserver, such as `value` (which, as we know, is only *initialized* from the `value` attribute): http://jsfiddle.net/L4e1kkfj/