# How can I find and access a JavaScript property ('Blazor') of 'window' with a (GreaseMonkey) user script?

Tags: javascript, blazor, greasemonkey

With the following (GreaseMonkey) user script I am trying to find (and later access) a JavaScript object (namely 'Blazor'):

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Test
// @version      1
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-end
// ==/UserScript==

window.addEventListener ("load", doStuff);

function doStuff() { 
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("window.hasProperty('Blazor'): " + window.hasOwnProperty("Blazor"));
        console.log("'Blazor' in window:           " + ('Blazor' in window));
        console.log(window);
    }, 2000);    
}
```

When I run the script (i.e., reload the page), I get the following output in Firefox' console:

[image: Screenshot of the Firefox JavaScript console]

So `window.Blazor` can not be found. However, when I inspect (click on) the `window` object I can see the `Blazor` property:

[image: Screenshot of the Firefox JavaScript console]

Calling `'Blazor' in window` in the console also returns `true`.

Why is this property of `window` not (yet?) available and how can I find and access it?

**Update:**

Based on [madalinivascu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68014782/1824721) I tried the following:

```
function doStuff() {
  console.log("<doStuff>");
  
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      console.log("checking for Blazor");
      if ('Blazor' in window) {
        console.log("Blazor found");
        clearInterval(interval);
        resolve(window.Blazor);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
  
  promise.then(successCallback, failureCallback);
  
  console.log("</doStuff>");
}

function failureCallback(error) {
  console.log("failure: " + error);
}

function successCallback(result) {
  console.log("success: " + result);
}
```

which results in the following output:

[image: Screenshot of the Firefox console]

So the function checking for Blazor is called indefinitely without success in finding it.

Comment: the `Blazor` variabile is intitalized **after** the windows load event, you need to listen to an event generated by the `Blazor` object initiating(if it has any), another solution will be a timeout function to wait for `Blazor `to initiate, this does not guarantee that `Blazor` will initiate in that time frame

Comment: Thank you. Since I don't know any events I could listen to, I have tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750518/javascript-waiting-until-property-of-an-element-is-ready-to-continue) which is the timeout function you described. Unfortunately, it does not work: Although `console.log(window)` already showed my the window including the `Blazor` property, the timeout function that regularly checked for it (in the meantime) did not find it.

Comment: Is it possible the "window" you get in Greasemonkey is not the same "window" that has the Blazor property?

Comment: @MisterMagoo Thank you, that lead to the right path! Apparently, the script runs in another environment. Using [script injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485122/accessing-variables-from-greasemonkey-to-page-vice-versa/13485650#13485650) I was able to access the 'real' window object (and thus Blazor).

Comment: I'd suggest you add your own answer and close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use [script injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485122/accessing-variables-from-greasemonkey-to-page-vice-versa/13485650#13485650), since the GreaseMonkey script runs in another context and thus gets another `window` object.

More precisely, attaching the function `doStuff` with `addJS_Node` defined in  [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485122/accessing-variables-from-greasemonkey-to-page-vice-versa/13485650#13485650) (`addJS_Node (null, null, doStuff);`) instead of using `window.addEventListener ("load", doStuff);` works.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for the variable using a setInterval and a promise

```
function doStuff() { 
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
          if(window.Blazor || window.hasOwnProperty('Blazor')) {
              clearInterval(interval);
              resolve(window.Blazor);//rezolve promise with the balzor variable
          }
        }, 200);//check every 200ms for the blazor variable
    })
    promise.then(function(blazor) {
        console.log(blazor);//do other stuf with the blazor variable
    })    
}
```

Comment: Thank you. There are closing brackets (`})`) missing. Could you please clarify, where they should go? I suppose before `promise.then...` though then I had no success with that approach, yet. (The check `if ('Blazor in window)` at some points stops but the promise is never called.)

Comment: sory, they should go before `promise.then`, updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. I have updated my question accordingly to explain what I did and what the outcome is.

Comment: better check if window.Blazor is defined or window has propery Blazor `window.hasOwnProperty('Blazor ')`, see updated answer