# How to control transitions with multiple CSS class assignments from a single Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I have one div, with buttons that trigger JS functions to add/remove CSS classes to the div. I understand this is a common way of doing simple animations ("transitions"). Try pressing the first two buttons, one after another. The red div will teleport up and become semi transparent, then fade in and slide back down. It always works.

The third button simply executes the same code as the first two buttons, but from one function. I expected it to have the same visible effect: the div immediately would jump up from the translate and be transparent, then during the course of 1 second it would slide back to its normal spot and fade in to full opacity. But it does not - the button has no visible effect.

Why? How can I make this work?

Here is the JS, see the whole thing at the codepen link.

```
const div = document.getElementById('red-box')

function translateUp() {
  div.classList.remove('no-translate');
  div.classList.add('translate-up');
}

function noTranslate() {
  div.classList.remove('translate-up'); 
  div.classList.add('no-translate');
}

//why does this function not show any transition animation?
function both() {
  translateUp();
  noTranslate();
}
```

https://codepen.io/DMcCreepy/pen/BampPyB

No jQuery please :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the functions are executed immediately one after the another, with no time to see the effect. `transition` in CSS refers to when the class is applied (could be related to a CSS state like `:hover`), not to switching classes via JavaScript.

To add the 1 second delay in the JS, you can use `window.setTimeout`:

```
function both() {
  translateUp();
  window.setTimeout(noTranslate, 1000);
}
```

Comment: thanks! 
But the .translate-up class has no transition property, and when it is applied, the .no-translate class has already been removed, therefore the div has no transition property. Shouldn't the visual effect of the assignment therefore be instantaneous? 
https://codepen.io/DMcCreepy/pen/BampPyB

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understand correctly what you are asking, but as someone else pointed out, the browser probably wouldn't stop in the middle of a JS function to recompute all properties of an element. It would do that once no JS command is waiting for immediate execution.

Answer (score 0):

You are relying on the `div` getting rerendered and all its properties being recomputed before switching the class again with the second function. I am not sure entirely what order things are done in under the hood, but I am sure you cannot rely on constructions like this working in general. It is true that switching classes is a common way to do animations and maybe it is possible to work out a solution like that, but I have provided a workaround using a CSS animation. You can read more about animations here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations

```js
const div = document.getElementById('red-box')

div.addEventListener('animationend', reset);
function reset() {
  div.classList.remove('dropin');
}
function both() {
  div.classList.add('dropin');
}
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}

.box {
  height: 70px;
  width: 80px;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: none;
}
.box.dropin {
  animation-name: dropin;
}
@keyframes dropin {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, -40px);
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="red-box" class="box">div</div>

<button onclick='both()'>Do Both</button>
```

Comment: I had no idea that the computing of element properties wouldn't be completely in sync with the JS execution! Do you know what keywords would be good to learn more about this division of processes, or the order of things happening "under the hood"? Excellent answer, thanks

Comment: Every browser is different, but you could check this out https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-the-rendering-engine-and-tips-to-optimize-its-performance-7b95553baeda. Also, you can read the html, js and css specifications but those are very lengthy documents aimed at readers with a pretty advanced understanding of things.

Comment: Maybe someday I will try to make the original format I shared work. There seems to be some precedent for getting JS execution to wait for CSS/html, [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750518/javascript-waiting-until-property-of-an-element-is-ready-to-continue), [example 2](https://thewebdev.info/2021/04/11/how-to-make-a-javascript-function-wait-until-an-element-exists-before-running-it/). For now I will likely use your solution with keyframes. Setting a short timeout also seems to work, but it feels icky and less guaranteed. Thanks again!